# Speedup 3D array multiplication

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have the following code snippet, which multiplies each 2D cross section of a 3D array by a vector:

```
A = zeros(N,M);
for k = 1:M
   B = C(:,:,k);
   A(:,k) = B * f(:,k);
end
```

When I profile the code I see that for N=200, M = 25 this can be quite slow (relative to other parts of my code); in particular the line:

```
B=C(:,:,k)
```

can take up a large fraction of the total runtime. Is there some way I could speed this up?

Comment: Please post runnable code. What are `C`, `f`?

Comment: C is a NxNxM array, f is a NxM array

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) combined with [`permute`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to perform the required multiplications with singleton expansion, and then add along the appropriate dimension to compute the matrix multiplications.

Define example data:

```
N = 5;
M = 4;
C = rand(N,N,M);
f = rand(N,M);
```

Then the result is computed as

```
result = permute(sum(bsxfun(@times, C, permute(f,[3 1 2])),2), [1 3 2]);
```

As a check, compare with the result computed using the loop:

```
A = zeros(N,M);
for k = 1:M
   B = C(:,:,k);
   A(:,k) = B * f(:,k);
end
result./A
```

gives

```
ans =
     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: There is more operation with this solution, I don't think that this method will be faster.

Comment: @obchardon I think the number of elementary multiplications and additions is the same. But yes, it may be slower, specially because of `permute`

Comment: I tested it on my problem. For N=192, M=25 it runs slightly slower.